# My program does not save or load infomation in or from data base

Tags: c#-3.0

I created a database and three pages for a register & login form & the third is for a lottery between my usernames .
I don't have any errors but the whole thing is not using the data base,
it does not save or load from database .

This is my register form:

```js
   using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class _2 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void btnRegister_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string strcon = "Data Source=.;uid=sa;pwd=123;database=Login_Register";
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strcon);
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("strlogin", con);
        com.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        SqlParameter p1 = new SqlParameter("username", txtUserName.Text.ToString());
        SqlParameter p2 = new SqlParameter("email", txtEmail.Text.ToString());
        SqlParameter p3 = new SqlParameter("password", txtpassword.Text.ToString());
        com.Parameters.Add(p1);
        com.Parameters.Add(p2);
        com.Parameters.Add(p3);
        con.Open();
        Label4.Text ="ثبت نام با موفقیت انجام شد".ToString();
        Label4.Visible = true;
        con.Close();
        com.ExecuteNonQuery();

    }

    private SqlDbType ToString(object text)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class Label4
{
    internal static object Text;
    internal static bool Visible;
}

public class txtUserName
{
    internal static object Text;
    internal static bool Visible;
}

public class txtEmail
{
    internal static object Text;
    internal static bool Visible;
}
public class txtpassword
{
    internal static object Text;
    internal static bool Visible;
}
```

Comment: Mention problem specifically. Are you able to connect to DB? Where is code to save to database? What is name of Stored Procedure. Your question is very wide and we cannot debug it. So be specific please.

Comment: "Strlogin" is the name of routin that I checked the database login with
And I created a database also than u can see the table too

The thing is that I don't have any idea  " string strcon "
Works and did I write it wrong!!!

Answer (score 0):

Look at your code

```
 con.Open();
    Label4.Text ="ثبت نام با موفقیت انجام شد".ToString();
    Label4.Visible = true;
    con.Close();
    com.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

You are opening the connection, closing it and then executing.
it should be:

```
 con.Open();
    Label4.Text ="ثبت نام با موفقیت انجام شد".ToString();
    Label4.Visible = true;
    com.ExecuteNonQuery();
 con.Close();//close connection after execute.
```

also it would be a good idea to add try/catch block around it - in case connection cannot be opened